# Timer is not changing the sprite

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game with sprite effects. The player has the ability to change their "Iceblade" for a certain amount of time. After 2 seconds, I would like the effect to revert to the normal "Iceblade". Therefore, I would need a timer within Unity. I tried for quite some time and can't quite make this work.

Here is my sample code:

```
if     (other.gameObject.CompareTag("IcePickup"))
{
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timer ++;
        Blade1 = GameObject.Find("Blade1");
        Blade1.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = IceBlade;
        if (Blade1.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = IceBlade)
    {
//i put a timer here but i cant figure out why is isnt working and print isnt showing.
        if (timer > 2)
        {
            Blade1.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = BladeNormal;
            print("working");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check if they are equal you should have wrote it like this

```
  if (Blade1.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite == IceBlade)
```

and

```
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
```

only happens once when `other.gameObject.CompareTag("IcePickup")` is true 
and here

```
timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        timer ++;
```

you are decreasing the timer value while increasing it

so this obviously isn't a timer. to make a timer  `timer -= Time.deltaTime;` must be called in `Update` to be able to count ,also you can use `coroutines`, [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225213/c-countdown-timer.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/valryon/9915075) are implementations of both ways